# Deployments dissappear after a couple of hours. Cirlce Ci, Nuxt, Dream Host

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, nuxt.js, hosting

I just started working on a project that was created with Nuxt and a CI pipeline using Cirlce CI that detects changes in the repository and upload files via SFTP to DreamHost.

We also have a netlify cms setup that sends .md files to the repository that are read and displayed on the page.

Now to the weird part.
Whenever I change something in the repository (push from my local repo, or use the cms) the changes appear on the site as they should. They correctly trigger a rebuild within circle.ci, which completes successfully and when I look at the live site they are present.

However when checking back a couple hours later they have dissapeared. The changes are still present in the github repository, but they are inconsistent with the state of the live page which has reverted to its previous state.
I can manually trigger rebuilds within circle.ci but the same thing occurs, i can see the changes for some time, then they dissapear.

I don't even know where to start looking for the problemect.
Any leads, or well aimed shots in the dark would be greatly appreciated, many thanks!

Edit.

I think this might be relevant: Every 12 hours we trigger a rebuild on the page, mostly to check for outdated content and deliver freshly rendered pages. When i checked the site index under the _nuxt pages, i see the following:

[image: Page Index]

There are older versions of the scripts that are correct and new versions that are incorrect, those new versions are then referenced, resulting in the content being false.

Why are the automatic rebuilds 'overwriting' the old build?
Where can i find out more about those triggers?

[image: successfull build in question]

Comment: Your issue is probably some cache issue no? What about always deleting the previous versions and invalidating the cache thanks to the hash of the file?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think it might be even simpler. The automated rebuild was pulling from the wrong branch, essentially overwriting my changes and those from the CMS.

Comment: Haha, tell me if the issue is fixed. I'll post an answer if it does.

Comment: Yep! Problem got solved :D The scheduled job no longer overwrites the manually updated content!

Answer (score 0):

OP's issue was mainly coming from the fact that the app was pulling from the wrong branch.

Fixing that one, did it.